# xinetd apache2-proxy service unavailable

Tags: apache-httpd, xinetd

I'm using the filesharing service `F*EX` [F*EX](http://fex.rus.uni-stuttgart.de) . If I run the service without a `proxy` I can reach it and it works. The service is controlled by `xinetd`. Now a `apache2` is configured to run as proxy and a redirection to `port 443`, but the service is unreachable. I got neither error messages from xinetd nor from apache2.

The output of `netstat -tulpnq` :

```
tcp  0  0 127.0.0.1:9988    0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN      15302/xinetd
```

Apache2 config file http:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName fex.myserver.de
    Redirect / https://fex.myserver.de
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache2 config file http:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>

ServerName fex.myserver.de
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9988/
ProxyPreserveHost On

    DocumentRoot /home/fex
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/fex/htdocs/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    *SSL OPTIONS GO HERE*
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

`xinetd.d/fex :`

```
# default: on
# description: F*EX web server
#
service fex
{
    socket_type             = stream
    log_type                = FILE /var/log/xinetd
    log_on_success          = PID HOST EXIT DURATION
    log_on_failure          = PID HOST EXIT DURATION
    wait                    = no
    type                    = unlisted
    protocol                = tcp
    bind                    = 127.0.0.1
    port                    = 9988
    cps                     = 10 2
    user                    = fex
    groups                  = yes
    server                  = /home/fex/bin/fexsrv
    nice                    = 0
    disable                 = no
}
```